# grunt-contrib-compass not work in npm

Tags: css, sass, npm, gruntjs, compass

i had installed npm and grunt and then installed grunt-contrib-compass.
but when i run grunt. i have this error

```
Running “compass:dist” (compass) task
Warning: not found: compass Use –force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings
```

and this my gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    compass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                sassDir: 'sass',
                cssDir: 'css'
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        css: {
            files: '**/*.scss',
            tasks: ['compass']
        }
    }
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the Compass Ruby gem, as detailed [here](http://thesassway.com/beginner/getting-started-with-sass-and-compass). Basically you need to have installed Ruby, and then using that you can install the Compass gem and grunt-contrib-compass should work